# RealmSwift needs to be rebuilt. Is there an update I can download?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, realm

The MakeSchool tutorials have been built using various builds of Swift, which is okay for the most part. However, the Framework, RealmSwift, needs to be rebuilt, which my Mac is refusing to open for security reasons.
Is there a new build for the current version of Swift available?

Comment: 0.98.6 claims to support Swift 2.2 - is this the version you are having security issues with? What is the security problem?

Comment: Make sure you're using a version of Realm built for the version of Swift you're using. You can learn more about Swift's binary compatibility here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2. Alternatively, you could build Realm from source using CocoaPods, Carthage or Xcode. Realm supports a number of different installation methods, all described step by step here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation

Comment: Yes, I'm using Swift 2.2. Here's a screenshot: (http://www.mellows.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Screen-Shot-2016-04-03-at-5.21.07-PM.png)

Comment: I did have trouble finding an up to date version of Realm, so this should help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the similar problem about the version of RealmSwift,(i was told to rebuild), and I refer to this website– https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/, and change the RealmSwift.framework to the correspondent version of swift, then the problem is solved.
Hope the website helps !